# I am try to finish my order Book code I can't figure out how summaries objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am try to finish my order Book code I can't figure out how summaries objects .
The code below is what is have currently .

```
const orderbook = [
    {
        "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
        "Side": "BID",
        "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
        "Quantity": "20",
        "OriginalQuantity": "20",
        "Price": "23700",
        "Status": "pending",
        "Updated": 0,
        "time": 1677680878610,
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
        "Side": "BID",
        "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
        "Quantity": "50",
        "OriginalQuantity": "50",
        "Price": "23674.52",
        "Status": "pending",
        "Updated": 0,
        "time": 1677681421267,
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
        "Side": "BID",
        "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
        "Quantity": "50",
        "OriginalQuantity": "50",
        "Price": "23714.99",
        "Status": "pending",
        "Updated": 0,
        "time": 1677681888376,
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
        "Side": "BID",
        "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
        "Quantity": "50",
        "OriginalQuantity": "50",
        "Price": "23674.52",
        "Status": "pending",
        "Updated": 0,
        "time": 1677681421267,
        "id": 2
    }
];
```

I am expecting to combine objects if they have same price.
I want to write a function that receive 1 argument (the array above) and executes the code below .

expected results :

```
const bidsOrders = 
[
{Price: "23714.99" ,"Quantity": "50", orders: 1},
{Price: "23700" ,"Quantity": "20", orders: 1},
{Price: "23674.52" ,"Quantity": "100", orders: 2}
];
```

Comment: "I want to write a function that receive 1 argument (the array above) and executes the code below" It seems you have forgotten to add the code you have tried.

Comment: I tried but it is not a good practice so I decide not include it , because I not have a idea for now how to do it. maybe some one else have an idea

Comment: SO works in a different way. You try something on your own and ask for a specific question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const orderbook = [
  {
    "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
    "Side": "BID",
    "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
    "Quantity": "20",
    "OriginalQuantity": "20",
    "Price": "23700",
    "Status": "pending",
    "Updated": 0,
    "time": 1677680878610,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
    "Side": "BID",
    "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "OriginalQuantity": "50",
    "Price": "23674.52",
    "Status": "pending",
    "Updated": 0,
    "time": 1677681421267,
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
    "Side": "BID",
    "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "OriginalQuantity": "50",
    "Price": "23714.99",
    "Status": "pending",
    "Updated": 0,
    "time": 1677681888376,
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "31135d2c-a5f0-11ed-b07a-10e7c6f7c62e",
    "Side": "BID",
    "Pair": "BTC/USDT",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "OriginalQuantity": "50",
    "Price": "23674.52",
    "Status": "pending",
    "Updated": 0,
    "time": 1677681421267,
    "id": 2
  }
];

const res = orderbook.reduce((arr, curr) => {
  let itemIndex = arr.findIndex(item => item.Price === curr.Price);
  if(itemIndex !== -1) {
    arr[itemIndex] = {
        Price: curr.Price,
      Quantity: parseInt(arr[itemIndex].Quantity) + parseInt(curr.Quantity),
      orders: (arr[itemIndex].orders || 1) + 1
    }
  } else {
    arr = arr.concat({
        Price: curr.Price,
      Quantity: parseInt(curr.Quantity),
      orders: 1
    })
  }
  return arr
}, []);

console.log(res);
```